# Hector (Cassandra) Delete Anomaly

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

Using hector (cassandra client) when I  try to do delete, it deletes the columns…but leaves the row key behind…does anyone know why, and how can I delete that row key as well ?

Comment: Found the answer on Cassandra chat --> http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#range_ghosts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected when using Cassandra. Since it deletes by writing tombstones the data is still there until the next compaction. Eventually it will go a way completely, but your application code must be aware that an empty row is the same as a deleted row.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it will go away in the next compaction that happens after the grace period for that row.

Check this out: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_%28data_store%29)